# How to add a scrollbar to a grid programmatically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following grid in the xaml file:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridPMP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" Margin="23,116,0,-330" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1238"/>
```

That grid is filled programmatically with this code .cs:

```
public void loadPMPTable()
    {
        gridPMP.Children.Clear();
        gridPMP.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        gridPMP.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        MetodosAux aux = new MetodosAux();
        String s = problemName.Content.ToString();
        String listaPath = "./DataSaved/" + s + "/ListaDeMateriales.txt";
        String arbolPath = "./DataSaved/" + s + "/ArbolDeMateriales";
        String RIPath = "./DataSaved/" + s + "/RegistroInventarios.txt";

        int cols = NumValue + 1;
        int rows = aux.numeroLineasFichero(listaPath) + 1;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(listaPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);

        String linea;

        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition CD = new ColumnDefinition();
            if (x==0)
            {
                CD.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(120);
            }
            else
            {
                CD.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(30);
            }
            //CD.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            gridPMP.ColumnDefinitions.Add(CD);
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
            //r.Height = GridLength.Auto;
            r.Height= new System.Windows.GridLength(30);
            gridPMP.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                if ((y == 0) && (x == 0)) //y=row index, x=column index
                {
                    TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    t.Width = 170;
                    t.IsReadOnly = true;
                    t.Text = "Elemento/Día";
                    t.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
                    Grid.SetColumn(t, x);
                    Grid.SetRow(t, y);
                    gridPMP.Children.Add(t);

                }
                else if ((y == 0) && (x >= 1))
                {
                    TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    t.Width = 170;
                    t.IsReadOnly = true;
                    t.Text = x.ToString();
                    t.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
                    Grid.SetColumn(t, x);
                    Grid.SetRow(t, y);
                    gridPMP.Children.Add(t);
                }
                else if (x == 0)
                {
                    TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    t.Width = 170;
                    t.IsReadOnly = true;
                    linea = file.ReadLine();
                    t.Text = linea;
                    t.FontWeight = FontWeights.DemiBold;
                    Grid.SetColumn(t, x);
                    Grid.SetRow(t, y);
                    gridPMP.Children.Add(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.PreviewTextInput += textBoxValidator;
                    tb.Width = 170;
                    tb.Text = "0";
                    Grid.SetColumn(tb, x);
                    Grid.SetRow(tb, y);
                    gridPMP.Children.Add(tb);
                }
            }
        }
        file.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }//end loadPMPTable()
```

The number of columns and rows change depending on the structure of some files. So when there are more than 8 rows the grid doesnt display the data because there isnt enough space. That's why I want to make the grid scrollable. How can I do this programmatically or from the xaml file? I tried it from the xaml file but I didnt get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it inside a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="gridPMP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Of course I have already tried that and it doesn't work. It doesn't show any scrollbar.

Comment: The Scrollbar will be shown when your grid's width or height is greater than the scrollviewers width or height. Also try setting horizontalscrollbar visibility and verticalscrollbarvisibility in your ScrollViewer to True.

Comment: P.S if you want to show a collection of items, it's always better to use an ItemsControl such as ListBox or ListView which inherently supports scrollbars.

Comment: "programatically"

Comment: @JoshNoe "or from the xaml file".